# $N$th term of sequence

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series

I have a sequence:

$$1,\;2,\;3,\;4,4,4,\;5,5,5,5,\;6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,\ldots$$

In words the $i$th term of sequence is $$\min(k \;|\; k \le i \text{ and }  \max(^kC_x)\ge i)$$ I want to find the $i$th term of sequence but I cant think of a way other than checking for minimum $k$ such that $^kC_{k/2}$ is greater than $i$ is satisfied. Is there a better way to get nth term of this sequence.

Comment: oeis gives 1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6 as Number of Lucas numbers (A000032) <= n, but I didn't see the above sequence in there.

Comment: The sequence explicitly is not there but if you take aC[a/2] where a is the ith term of the terms that is reverse the way the sequence is defined then it detects a sequence. I am trying to see If I can reverse this result

Comment: To verify: is $^kC_x$ a notation denoting "$k$ choose $x$", sometimes written as $k\choose x$?

Comment: Yes it can be written that way